# call a function in javascript as global function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main function in javascript that is function a() { some code here } and I also have a child function in this main function that looks like

```
function a() {

    function b() {

        // some code here
    }

}
```

now I want to call the function b directly. then how to do this.

Comment: Functions declaring functions. How perverse! ;) Couldn't you simply cut/paste b() to have it on the same level as a() (global script level, therefore global visibility) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try explicitly exposing `b` to the global object like this:

```
function a() {

    function b() {

        // some code here
    }

    window.exposed = b;
}
```

Comment: And if the host environment doesn't have a window object?

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  You can, however do something like:

```
function a() {

    this.b = function () {

        some code here
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
var x = new a();
a.b();
```

You can also create an object literal with your function:

```
var a = {
  b: function ()
     {
       //some code here
     }
};
```

And then just say:

```
a.b();
```

You could also create a property on the function object itself, and access it that way:

```
function a()
{
};

a.b = function ()
{
  //Some code here
};
```

And then call it with:

```
a.b();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare function b inside of function a, just call it like so

```
function b() {
some code here
}

function a() {
b();
}
```

Comment: This is the obvious answer, but it's missing a discussion of how to access the locals of `a` from `b` i.e. how to hoist out the locals of `a` to make the closures equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions here, the only one I think that will suit is to attach the function to the global object so it looks like a declared function. The only difference is that it won't be available until `a` runs:

```
function a() {

  // Protect against ES5 strict mode, assume function is called as global code
  if (typeof this !== undefined) {
    this.b = function() { /* whatever */ };
  }
}
```

or perhaps the following suits your coding style better:

```
function a() {

  function b() { /* whatever */};

  if (typeof this !== undefined) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

Called simply as:

```
a();
```

then in ES3 or ES5 non-strict mode, it will work as expected. To overcome ES5 strict limitations where the above will result in a's *this* being undefined, call *a* as global code and set its *this* explicitly:

```
a.call(this);
```

or with some other suitable reference to the global object.

I have stayed away from using *window* since that is less reliable, not least because non–browser hosts will likely not have a *window* object.